# C# switch from local db to external (Azure) db causes errors

Tags: c#, azure

I have used the built in Database that comes with Visual studio by using Code First with Entity Framework. Now I wanted to move to an external database so I created one and saved the connections string. So I connected to my azure database by supplying the connection string in the db context constructor. Now though, the problem is that Entity Framework isn't able to create the necessary tables. When I run my application and try to access something, I get `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.'`
And I assume this is beacuse my azure db is empty. Why doesn't Entity Framework create the tables?

Comment: Solved it, had to run migration on the new database aswell!

Comment: If you solved it, can you answer with your method ?

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I had forgotten to run migration on the new database:

*Add-Migration newDb
*Update-Database